# Angular 6 & Vagrant issues

Tags: node.js, windows, vagrant

So, I've been trying to build a MEAN (MongoDB Express Angular NodeJS) stack server to use for academic teaching purposes, as a student sandbox/training environment. I can install all packages fine, the problems appear when trying to generate a new project inside my Linux box. It always halts towards the end, with an error about "Busy File" or something along those lines, and thus the project is missing crucial files to run with the command 'ng serve'.

Another problem is the sync between host and guest, I am running Windows 10 as host, and using Debian 9 as the guest, and when editing and saving files on the host, NodeJS compiler is not triggering nor synchronizing my changes to the server.

I've tried some Vagrant plugins, such as FS-Notify and WinNFSD, but to no luck. I remember reading something about Nodewatch being the culprit, but I am not sure and I don't have much experience around Angular, Node and Vagrant together.

I've browsed the Github repository Vagrant Plugins, https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/wiki/Available-Vagrant-Plugins, but can't seem to find an appropriate solution to run an isolated MEAN stack Debian with only Vagrant and VirtualBox on a Windows host.

I am using Windows 10 as host, Debian 9 as the guest. Windows host is using Vagrant 2.1.4, and VirtualBox version 5.2.18. (I've tried using Docker, but it requires and consumes too many resources, unfortunately.)

I've noticed that there seem to be quite a few people with similar issues.
I would greatly appreciate any help or input on what to do. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.entrostat.com/vagrant-ubuntu-docker-windows/

Following this article worked just fine for me.
Don’t forget to start a second PowerShell and run

`vagrant fsnotify`

The only issue I’m currently trying to resolve is tslint going crazy in VS. Code and WebStorm due to the host system not containing node_modules.

I’ll get back here when I find a solution.

Comment: Great! Any news on the tslint thing?

Comment: Sorry, I am not using vagrant anymore. I switched to docker for all my projects. I think a workaround was to just use a different provider for file sharing and / or Linux Subsystem for Windows. So for me Docker was the "Solution"